# should I add "javascript:" in front of html tag function?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do I need to specify the JavaScript protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321469/when-do-i-need-to-specify-the-javascript-protocol)

for example

```
 <body onload="javascript:something();">
```

in this code,  should I put `javascript:` ?

some of the codes attatch  `javascript:`,

but some don't.

what is the safe and correct?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321469/when-do-i-need-to-specify-the-javascript-protocol

Comment: Okay, that's really really weird: I wrote the comment above starting with the word "Duplicate". I **did not** write the one starting with the word "possible" that is showing up as from me. (Flagged for mods.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: That comment is automatic, it's generated if you are the first who voted for a particular duplicate... See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/autocomment-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution would be to avoid explicit use of JavaScript in your markup altogether and to use something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to extract it all to a separate file; you can then do something like this:

```
$(function()
{
    // This will be run when the document is loaded.
    alert('foo');

    $('#some-link').click(function()
    {
        // This will be run when the element with id `some-link` is clicked.
        alert('bar');
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 For separation of concerns using jQuery

Answer (score 3):

No. Just use your javascript.

> ```
> <body onload="something();">
> ```

`javascript:` can be used with the `href` attribute of `a` element.

> ```
> <a href="javascript:something();">
> ```

But just for the protocol, I prefer using the `onload` method.

Comment: That's not good advice. The JavaScript pseudo-protocol shouldn't be used for links either. You should attach a handler to the onclick event that returns false if you want clicking a link to execute JavaScript code.

Comment: @Jimmy: It's not a "protocol", it's a "scheme". And it's not a pseudo-anything: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-hoehrmann-javascript-scheme-01 It's been in IE since v3 (yes, v3) and in all major browsers since.

Comment: To be fair, an anchor point may not make sense semantically, in which case a click handler on a semantically neutral element is a better option than an <a>. However, that's not a reason to avoid the 'javascript:' scheme.

Comment: Just to be clear, you dont need it, and it will be ignored.

Comment: JavaScript is traditionally known as a ‘pseudo-protocol’ because unlike almost every other scheme it does not represent a location, but an action to be performed on the current location. A URL that is not a locator is something that doesn't really make much sense, and indeed problems with accepting `javascript:` URLs where a locator was expected have caused innumerable security holes in the past. There are also usability problems, eg. middle-click link for new tab... oh dear, I've got an empty tab with a JavaScript error in it instead.

Comment: Now-documented in a Draft or not, `javascript:` URLs are a total disaster and should never be used in a web page. They were one of the many dreadful mistakes Netscape made when trying to attain a competitive advantage for Navigator by breaking the web in other browsers. Whilst some of those mistakes have been rectified and airbrushed out of history (eg. `<layer>`), `javascript:` hangs around like a bad smell. For anything but bookmarklets, avoid avoid avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest something like

```
<body>
...
<script>
function something() {}
window.onload = something;
</script>
```