# why do we need javascript: while making inline javascript calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We have lot of legacy inline javascript code for img onclick , href clicks ets and those clicks starts with javascript:

```
javascript:showpopup();
```

why do we need javascript: before calling the javascript functions.

any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use it at all.  Just return false in your anchor tags.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321469/when-do-i-need-to-specify-the-javascript-protocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For inline event handlers like `onclick` or `onmouseover` you don't need the `javascript:` part.

```
<a href="javascript:you_need_it_here();" onmouseover="but_not_here();">Link</a>
```

Without `javascript:` in the `href`, clicking that link would try to take you to somewhere like this:

```
http://www.example.com/something/you_need_it_here();
```

See @Ignacio's answer for the reason.

Answer (score 4):

The `javascript:` scheme indicates to the browser that it's JavaScript code and not a relative path from the current page's base URL.