# How to stop the jump when clicking on an anchor link?

Tags: html, tags, click, anchor

Is there a way of avoiding the jump when clicking on an anchor link? So that the view does not change.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the "jumping" code?

Comment: if you don't want the view to change, why have an anchor link? Please clear this out.

Comment: I know this is super old, but to answer @JoeriHendrickx sometimes this is not an option. For instance I do A/B split testing which requires modifications to be made to a clients page after load. I cannot edit their original code but must change the behaviour to determine through data if it should be done or not. This question is 100% valid.

Answer (score 25):

The most semantic and meaningful approach to this problem would be to handle the onclick event from within JavaScript. Ideally this file would be best to be stored in a seperate file, however, including a in-line script within your problem file would suffice. Here's how i'd recommended approaching this problem if your already using a JavaScript library like jQuery.

**Assign an ID**
Include an id attribute to your anchor so it's able to be selected using jQuery:

```
<a href="#anchor" id="mylink" title="Title Here">Link Text</a>
```

**Bind click event**
From within your JavaScript file / in-line script include the following:

```
$('#mylink').click(function(event) {

    // This will prevent the default action of the anchor
    event.preventDefault();

    // Failing the above, you could use this, however the above is recommended
    return false;

});
```

The method above is explained in full using the jQuery API websites: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: sometimes you want to disable the jump and carry out all other default behavior such as appending #anchor to the location without a page reload. event.preventDefault() alone will not work.

Answer (score 16):

Just use:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Text</a>
```

Comment: I marked this down cos this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321469/when-do-i-need-to-specify-the-javascript-protocol

Comment: event.preventDefault(); is a better option

Answer (score 1):

You could use Javascript to prevent the default behaviour of the link, a simple example being:

```
<a href="#myanchor" onclick="return false;">link</a>
```

Comment: the positon of the divs with the id does not change when I use your snippet

Comment: I marked this down cos inline js is a nightmare - in my opinion

Comment: obviously it does the job on stopping jump but also stops the event from happening