# Shift+Click on anchor link redirection Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, anchor, new-window

When I Shift+Click on anchor link it redirects me to anchor link's location and also open in new window.

When i use Shift+Click:
I just want to open in new page, source page dont want to redirect.

When i use Only Click:
I want to redirect Source page to anchor link's location.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078817/how-to-stop-the-jump-when-clicking-on-an-anchor-link

Comment: @helb : Please read question again

Comment: Well, you can use it together with checking whether the Shift key is pressed, like this: http://codepen.io/helb/pen/ryogyj. That would work for what you're asking, but there are other ways to open a new window/tab (middle click, context menu, …), and there is probably no single reliable way to mess with browser's default behavior.

Comment: Thank you, worked.

Comment: I'm glad i could help, but… don't rely on this method too much, it's quite easy to break, as mentioned.

Comment: Yes, you are right @helb