# Best way to use javascript in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html

There are many ways to use JavaScript. When I use JavaScript with an anchor, I write code like this and I think this way is right.

```
<a href="#;" onclick="alert('hi');">Method One</a>
```

But my co-worker uses JS like this.

```
<a href="javascript:alert('hi');">Method Two</a>
```

Is there a coding standard or are both methods correct?

Comment: Standard is to use `addEventListener()` so that your markup is free from javascript

Comment: First one will also make `href` invoke the `#` so page will scroll up..Use `event` as argument and use `e.preventDefault()` or use second approach..There are few other approaches too to achieve this...

Comment: This is the first time I see the style your coworker uses but there's no need to define "javascript:" at the beginning. That's the default.

Comment: @GastónSánchez, Test it out...I guess it is needed...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript function in href vs. onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick)

Comment: There is no real "standard" for something like this. I would say that my preferred and what I mostly see is using `addEventListener()` as @gurvinder372 suggests or the onclick method.

Comment: The best way is to avoid both. For good maintainability you should keep `html`, `css` and `js`  in separate files and assign listeners using `addEventListener`

Comment: @GastónSánchez I already tested and it doesn't work without `javascript:`

Comment: @RayonDabre oh I answered too fast. Didn't notice the script is inside href and not onClick. My bad. It is a lot more common to use the first style than the second though.

Comment: @GastónSánchez, I was just about to mention that..;P

Comment: @Mystika if you look at the possible duplicate one of the answers explains that the `this` keyboard in the `onclick` refers to the DOM element, whereas in the `href` it refers to the window. That is really the only difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the different methods of putting JavaScript code in an <a>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245868/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-methods-of-putting-javascript-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: Inline JavaScript is, generally speaking, a bad idea, and 99% of the time you're much better off separating concerns, and using a library, such as jQuery, or whatever similar toolset that your framework of choice recommends.

Nonetheless, to answer your question, if you must use inline JavaScript, I recommend that you omit the "JavaScript:" keyword. It specifies a "pseudo-protocol," and is not necessary for modern browsers to interpret the code. It is a relic from the last decade, and there is a bug with some versions of IE:

> "There is one (somewhat obscure) bug with the javascript protocol - in
>   Internet Explorer*, it will think you are leaving the page when you
>   click the link. If you are using window.onbeforeunload, then your
>   navigate-away message will appear at this time. For this reason alone,
>   we've stopped using the javascript protocol completely so we don't
>   have this bug show up because we forgot to check for it when we add a
>   navigate-away message to some page."

[When do I need to specify the JavaScript protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321469/when-do-i-need-to-specify-the-javascript-protocol)

https://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/504856-javascript-pseudo-protocol-event-handlers

Answer (score -3):

Both the ways are ok but in first way you should use a external JS file. Otherwise it is ok.
For small tasks and events second ways is good.