# How to dissable href and call onclick at once with(out) jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I found some answers for this question, but non of them worked for me.
What I wants is to call function `myFunc()` without refreshing page where `href` wants.
This `href` is doing his job with `GET` request and I want it to stay in cause if someone have script block. It have to work without scripts too.
But when somebody hadn't dissabled script, then I wants to not go where `href` redirect but do `myFunc()` onclick 

I had Tried something like this:
at javascript:

```
function onClickFunc(somedata){
  event.preventDefault();
  myFunc(somedata);
}
```

at html:

```
<a onclick="javascript:onClickFunc({{ some_django_data.id }})" href="?current={{ some_django_data.id }}{% if other_django_data %}&page={{ other_django_data.number }}{% endif %}">
```

When I replace `href` body with `#` and put `javascript:myFunc({{ some_django_data.id }})` inside `onclick` then it works.
Bit it's not soloution because people with script block would lose possibility of using my site.
What is wrong with this solution?

Comment: Put javascript:void(0); in href.

Comment: your `event` is not defined!!

Comment: (Except on [old] IE)

Comment: @Rahi Had you read what I wrote?
I wants href to stay and it's my whole problem.

Comment: Add `return false` to `onclick` and call only function. Dont put javascript into `href`. Use redirect from function

Comment: @MartaWiśniowiecka: Even if Rahi missed it, "Have you read what I wrote?" is not constructive. Just repeat it.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. `onXyz` attribute-style handlers contain *JavaScript code*, so there's no need for the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol.
2. Because you're coding a function call, if you want access to the event object, you need to pass it into the function

So:

```
onclick="onClickFunc(event, {{ some_django_data.id }})"
```

Then

```
function onClickFunc(event, somedata) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Stops the default behavior of following the link
    // ...
}
```

---

If you need to support really old browsers (or browsers hobbling themselves and *behaving* like really old browsers [I'm looking at you, IE9-IE11]), you'll need to allow for the possibility that `preventDefault` isn't present on the event object. The good news is, though, that `return false` in an `onXyz` attribute handler prevents the default action. So:

So *(note the `return`)*:

```
onclick="return onClickFunc(event, {{ some_django_data.id }})"
```

and *(note the `return` here too)*:

```
function onClickFunc(event, somedata) {
    if (event.preventDefault) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Stops the default behavior of following the link
    }
    // ...

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I added `event` argument, and `return false` as you recomended and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is on the right track, but you forgot to pass the event object to the javascript function.

**SEE THIS WORKING EXAMPLE:**

```js
function myfunc(event, data) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("HELLO");
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="myfunc(event, 'foo')" href="www.google.com">TESTER</a>
```

*Note: You do not really need to specify the JS protocol. Have a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321469/when-do-i-need-to-specify-the-javascript-protocol).*