# Why "javascript:function()" is used in href attribute of anchor tag to call an javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have my code like this and I want to call an JavaScript function which returns an website link. Which link I want to be the value of href="" attribute. So somewhere I got the solution to do so. But there wasn't defined that why to do so. Here's my code. I want to know why to call javascript function inside href attribute href="javascript:functionname()" is to be written rather than href="functionname()".

```js
function hyperlinker(){
  document.location.href="https://www.google.co.in";
  }
```

```html
<a href="javascript:hyperlinker()"> click to get new page </a>
```

Comment: I guess you *can*, but you really [shouldn't do either](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045): look up `addEventListener`

Comment: My guess is that it will interpret `javascript:` as a protocol much like it would interpret `http://` as a protocol otherwise it defaults to routing to some theorhetical route called `functionname()` on your server.

Comment: Can't you just do `onclick`? Why do you specifically need `href`

Comment: @HereticMonkey That question is specifically about a `javascript:` link with no code. It also doesn't answer this question about why you need the `javascript:` prefix.

Comment: @HereticMonkey That's an answer to a question that wasn't actually asked.

Comment: It doesn't really answer the question of why you can't just write `href="somefunc()"`

Comment: @HereticMonkey I tried, couldn't find one. I saw that one and rejected it.

Comment: Better dupe: [When do I need to specify the JavaScript protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2321469/215552)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having an anchor like

```
<a href="somefunc()">Click Me</a>
```

Would be interpreted as "try to navigate to the route somefunc()".  So you would be sent to `http://www.example.com/somefunc()`.  Where `http:` is the protocol of the current page you're on.

The `javascript:`, much like the `http:` and the `mailto:` and the `tel:` as well as any other prefix like that is the [**protocol** to use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL).  If you leave it off, you're leaving it up to the browser's default behavior.  For relative URLs (which is what you have written), [it will default to `http:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#Absolute_URLs_vs_relative_URLs) (Thanks Barmar)

> You don't need to include the protocol (the browser uses HTTP by
> default) or the port (which is only required when the targeted Web
> server is using some unusual port), but all the other parts of the URL
> are necessary.

See [MDN `<a/>` Tag `href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a):

> `href`
>
> The URL that the hyperlink points to. Links are not restricted to
> HTTP-based URLs — they can use any URL scheme supported by browsers:
>
> - Sections of a page with fragment URLs
> - Pieces of media files with media fragments
> - Telephone numbers with tel: URLs
> - Email addresses with mailto: URLs
> - While web browsers may not support other URL schemes, web sites can with registerProtocolHandler()

---

If your intention is to call some JavaScript function though, you shouldn't use `href` anyway, that's what `onclick` is for, or better still `addEventListener()` and if the anchor won't be "taking you anywhere", use a `<button/>` for accessibility.

> Anchor elements are often abused as fake buttons by setting their
> `href` to `#` or `javascript:void(0)` to prevent the page from
> refreshing, then listening for their `click` events .
>
> These bogus `href` values cause unexpected behavior when
> copying/dragging links, opening links in a new tab/window,
> bookmarking, or when JavaScript is loading, errors, or is disabled.
> They also convey incorrect semantics to assistive technologies, like
> screen readers.
>
> Use a `<button>` instead. In general, you should only use a hyperlink
> for navigation to a real URL.

Comment: It's not "guessing". If you leave the protocol off, it defaults to the same protocol as the current URL.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, that's the bit that I'm looking for.  I can't find where it defaults to the current protocol.

Comment: See the section on relative URLs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL